# Is it possible to filter output in Python depending on previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm developing a student project and my task is to analyze data from one dataframe. I've filtered it, prepared etc, and now I have to analyze it, but I have so many rows and it's difficult to do it manually. I have to find rows with one pattern: all of the data are the same, but one column is different. So, I've got:

| Name | Job | Salary | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Driver | 1300 | USA |
| Adam | Driver | 1300 | China |
| Nick | Driver | 1320 | USA |
| Nick | Driver | 1320 | USA |
| Joel | Teacher | 1900 | Brazil |
| Nick | Pilot | 2300 | Canada |
| Nick | Pilot | 2300 | Russia |

and I want to have:

| Name | Job | Salary | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Driver | 1300 | USA |
| Adam | Driver | 1300 | China |
| Nick | Pilot | 2300 | Canada |
| Nick | Pilot | 2300 | Russia |

I can simply use:

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Name','Job', 'Salary'], keep=False)])
```

but after this, I have also rows in which all of the data are the same as in other
(I have this, but I don't want to):

| Name | Job | Salary | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nick | Driver | 1320 | USA |
| Nick | Driver | 1320 | USA |

Is it possible somehow to do it?

Comment: By `one column is different.` you imply the column `Country`, right?

Comment: You don't want the same job to be assigned to more than one name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your code sample, you want to find groups not with **any**
3 columns with the same value, but with **the first 3 columns** with
the same value (and different values in the fourth column).

One way: After you generated your *df1*, remove pairs of duplicated rows:

```
df2 = df1[~df1.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Another, maybe simpler solution is to start from your original *df*,
group it by *['Name','Job', 'Salary']* and leave only groups which have
more than one unique *Country*:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Name','Job', 'Salary']).filter(
    lambda grp: grp.Country.unique().size > 1)
```